# Read second column of csv

Tags: csv, julia

I have this CSV data file that looks like

```
a,b
1,2
3,4

data = readdlm("my/local/path", ',')
```

however, when I access `data[1]`, I'm only getting `a`, I thought it supposes to be `[a,b]`? Doing things like `data[1:2]` gets me the first column only.

Any idea how can I access the second column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for [readdlm](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=readdlm#Base.readdlm):

> Read a **matrix** from the source where each line gives one row...

So use `data[row,col]` syntax to get each element